# Moment JS - convert user-submitted date/time/timezone to timezone-independent UTC

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, momentjs

In my Node.js app a user submits a date, time, and timezone (separate form fields). Using Moment Timezone, I am trying to save the date adjusted for no offset (timezone independent).

The code below works, but is there a simpler/cleaner way to achieve the same result? Having to multiply the offset by -1 seems hackish:

```
const userDate = new Date(req.body.date + ' ' + req.body.time);
const userTz = req.body.tz;

const offset = moment.tz(userTz).utcOffset();
const utc = moment(userDate).utcOffset(-1*offset).format('YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss');
```

Example Input:

```
Date: 09/06/2016 (via Bootstrap date picker)
Time: 07:41:00 (via Bootstrap time picker)
Timezone: America/New_York (UTC/GMT -4 hours)
```

Returns (correctly):

```
2016-09-06T11:41:00Z
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: moment.js, as the utc variant you can use.  eg.  moment.utc()  -> http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/

Comment: How can using .utc() without original timezone knowledge properly adjust the offset?

Comment: not tested. you can chain something like moment(userDate).tz(userTz).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`tz`](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/) to create a date in user entered timezone, for which there is no direct way in javascript date object. Once you have the date reconstructed with `moment.tz` go ahead and convert it to `utc`, now *format it however you want*.

Also, check your solution(*shown in Question*) in a browser running from a different timezone, I am pretty sure that it will give different results.

```js
let req = {};
 req.body = {date: "09/06/2016",
             time: "07:41:00",
             tz: "America/New_York"};

const a = moment
           .tz(req.body.date+ " " + req.body.time,"MM/DD/YYYY HH:mm:ss" ,req.body.tz)
           .utc()
           .format();

console.log(a);
```

```html
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! One small thing I didn't clarify is my req.body.date is in MM/DD/YYYY format, not DD/MM/YYYY so the date format strings need to be updated accordingly.

Comment: For the output, you would not use `MM/DD/YYYY` with `T` and `Z`.  Those signify ISO8601, which only allows `YYYY-MM-DD`